# Django one line datetime if null

Tags: python, django

I'd like to do this:

```
class VenteGroupee(models.Model):
    date_v_debut = models.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.now,
        editable=True
    )
    date_v_fin = models.DateTimeField(
        default=None,
        null=True,
        editable=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - ({1} -> {2})".format(
            self.id,
            DateFormat(self.date_v_debut).format('jS F Y H:i')  if self.date_v_debut else 'Infinity',
            DateFormat(self.date_v_fin).format('jS F Y H:i') if self.date_v_fin else 'Infinity'
        )
```

but the two last lines are ugly (`date_v_debut` and `date_v_fin` may be null so I need to check).
Is there a nice "pythonic"/"djangostic" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a helper function to format the date.

```
def format_date(value)
    return DateFormat(value).format('jS F Y H:i') if value else 'Infinity'
```

Then your `__str__` method simplifies to

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{0} - ({1} -> {2})".format(
        self.id,
        format_date(self.date_v_debut),
        format_date(self.date_v_fin),
    )
```